# Search a substring within a string using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to search for `{json code}` within the following string

(function(r,t){var a={json code};if(...)remaining js code}

I am using PowerShell, but just can't seem to crack it. Can someone please help?

I have tried the following options and just don't know regex well enough

`$text1 = "<script>(function(r,t){var a={json code};if(...)remaining js code}</script>";`

Option 1
`$jsonvalue = $text1 -Match 'a={<content>}';
$jsonvalue;`

Upon execution I get False

Option 2
`$jsonvalue = $text1 -match "a=(.*)"; 
$jsonvalue;`
Upon execution I get True

Option 3
`$jsonvalue = $text1 -match "a=(?<content>.)*;if("
$jsonvalue;`

Upon execution I get True with the following error

`parsing "a=(?<content>.)*;if(" - Not enough )'s.
RegEx.ps1:4 char:1
+ $jsonvalue = $text1 -match "a=(?<content>.)*;if("
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: -match "*a=(?<content>.*)*;if("

a=(.*)}

Comment: Please post your actual code or at least a [MCVE] in your question. Not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this is just a representation of your actual data. Without the actual data, here is a representation of the actual answer:

```
$t = '(function(r,t){var a={json code};if(...)remaining js code}'
$t -match 'a={(.+)};'
$code = $matches[1]
```

A little info about the regex. It looks for `a={` then it matches any characters up until it finds `};`. It saves those as a subexpression which in Powershell can be accessed via the $matches array.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it is a representation of the actual code and your solution works. Appreciate the help.

Comment: By the way, I also realized that I had to strip out the newline characters from $t for the regex to work.